# Jenkins pipeline Parameter to hold an array

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've two pipelines say - `CallingPipeline` and `CalledPipeline` where `CallingPipeline` calls `CalledPipeline`(downstream pipeline)

In `CallingPipeline`, I create an array and I want to pass it to `CalledPipeline`. For that, I need to create a Parameter in `CalledPipeline` but I could not find parameter which holds an array. Could you please suggest which Parameter will hold an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you just join() and made it a delimited string and then split()/reformed it back to a list/array in the CalledPipeline?

All jenkins parameters boil down to String or Boolean afaik

Answer (score 1):

Use a string parameter. Serialize your data in CallingPipeline and deserialize it in CalledPipeline. This is a straightforward task using the Groovy classes [`JsonOutput`](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html#_jsonoutput) and [`JsonSlurper`](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html#json_jsonslurper). Compared to simple join / split this approach can be used even for more complex data (e. g. nested objects).

## CallingPipeline

```groovy
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

node {
    stage('test') {
        def myArray = [ 42, 'bar', 'baz' ]

        build job: 'CalledPipeline', parameters: [
            string(name: 'myParam', value: JsonOutput.toJson( myArray ) )
        ]
    }
}
```

## CalledPipeline

```groovy
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

node {
    stage('test') {
        echo "myParam: $myParam"

        def myParamObject = new JsonSlurper().parseText( myParam )
        for( def elem in myParamObject ) {
            echo "$elem"
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
myParam: [42,"bar","baz"]
42
bar
baz
```